# Angular2 editable form with service using Observables

Tags: forms, angular, observable, rxjs

I got a plunker here describing simple form http://plnkr.co/edit/YhtPpSmEgDEZpZ2BKNVA?p=preview

```
<form>
  <input       [(ngModel)]='model.name'/>
  <departments [(value)]  ='model.departmentId'></departments>
</form>
```

What it does: There is a service that provides data, form - shows ui for user with editable fields bound to model,  **departments_list.ts** component that shows list of departments and current person's department. User changes name - model name changed, user changes department by clicking on it - model's **departmentId** changed. User clicks on 'Save' and in console you can see that it is current model that on screen.
Everything works fine except this is a toy example because in real world you need to fetch data from server and there will be delays. I prepared in **service.ts** lines 11, 17 that need to be uncommented to use completely the same data but pretending it is fetched from server. And this is where I got stuck...

So the question - how to implement this kind of form in Angular2 using Observables with server delays?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Ok, you where close:

Instead of:

```
this.model = this.service.getPersonById(1);
```

you should go with:

```
this.service.getPersonById(1).subscribe((data) => this.model = data; )
```

This is your ( rewrited ) Plunker:
http://plnkr.co/edit/sS6as6VfEwtlvY5fNSpK?p=preview